# MP4 file for video.js - specification

Tags: html5-video, mp4, video.js

on my web application I use video.js to handle all video MP4 files. I have to specify MP4 file details for my video provider. 
I want to handle FF, chrome, IE8/9 and iPad by this format. 
Could you define a set of video MP4 file details which ensure that video.js will handle with this format (for example: codec, video/audio format, video format profile)? 
I do not know if it will be helpful, but I use mediainfo (http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to check MP4 file's details.

Answer (score 1):

Including the default code that is provided on the video js website should do enough to support the mp4 file you have (specifically "type='video/mp4'"), however, if you're intending to support Firefox, this won't be enough. FF doesn't support the mp4 file type so you'll need to encode an ogv or a webm. FF provides a plugin that can help here at firefogg.org

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a big advice for me. The thing is mp4 format can provide support for video in all browsers. 
In FF and IE8/win xp we get flash fallback support - but this is ok, I realize that by one video format I don't get HTML5 version of player in all browswers.
My goal is define a set of video MP4 file details which ensure that video.js works good in all browsers (in html5 and fallback version too).